# Need explanation on error reported from bufio package of golang

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  writeBuf := make([]byte, 1)

  fp, err := os.OpenFile("test.d", os.O_CREATE, 0777)
  bf := bufio.NewWriterSize(fp, 3)

  writeBuf = []byte("1")
  writeCount, err := bf.Write(writeBuf)
  fmt.Println(writeCount)

  writeBuf = []byte{'2'}
  writeCount, err = bf.Write(writeBuf)
  fmt.Println(writeCount)

  writeBuf = []byte{'3'}
  writeCount, err = bf.Write(writeBuf)
  fmt.Println(writeCount)

  writeBuf = []byte{'4'}
  writeCount, err = bf.Write(writeBuf)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error4:", err)
    os.Exit(-1)
  }
  fmt.Println(writeCount)

  bf.Flush()
  fp.Close()

}
```

Why does this give the error:

```
 1
 1
 1
 Error4: write test.d: bad file descriptor
 exit status 255
```

I thought that NewWriterSize of 3 means that after three bytes are written, the output is flushed. I am getting the error on the 4th write. If I change the NewWriterSize buffer size to 4, it works. For brevity, I have omitted error checks where error is not reported.

Comment: bufio.Writer flushes when there is no space for a Write, not when a Write fills the buffer.  There is space for the first three writes, but not the fourth.  The writer flushes on the fourth.

Comment: @BaytaDarell The error is reported before the bf.Flush()

Comment: Yes, the writer makes an internal call to flush the data on the fourth call to Write.  The writer will also flush whatever data is in the buffer when the application calls Flush, but the application does not get to that line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check the error returned from os.OpenFile. I expect it's erroring because you need to use O_RDWR or O_WRONLY in the flags (if you want to be able to write to the file). But using os.Create rather than os.OpenFile is easier unless you really need the perm option of os.OpenFile.

Comment: You are right, using os.Create works fine. OR-ing the other flags you specified did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what flags you or-ed, but you need either `os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE` or `os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREATE`.

Comment: Thats it. I was OR-ing all three flags :(